# How can I find the most liked images of the day on Instagram?

Tags: javascript, php, json, instagram

The Instagram API is really not that well documented.

Does anyone know of a way where I can find the most liked Instagram photos (of the day) by location? As in, what picture did most Danish people like today...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the location ID you want, you should be able to get popular photos by location using

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/{location-ID}/media/popular?MIN_TIMESTAMP={UNIX timestamp for beginning of day}&access_token={access token}
```

and you can search for a location ID using the location/search query, like so:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat={latitude}&lng={longitude}&access_token={access token}
```

in both of these URLs, {} represent variables that you need to define.

Reference:
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I got the GPS coordinates, (lat-long), put them in the url instead of {latitude} and {longitude} which gave me a list of locations.

I took one of the location ID's, and added the UNIX timestamp for yesterday's midnight. I also generated an access token.

The result was this URL:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/2608967/media/popular?MIN_TIMESTAMP=1381813200&access_token=25868257.761450e.aeec91b47540453a9024d7c40ce5eda1#

which gave me a 'page not found' on instagram...

Comment: Hi @Giveny. Did you succeed? I need the same thing.