# Find Instagram most liked photos of Iranian people of the day

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to find Instagram most liked photoes shared by Iranian people in last day and I must do it daily.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204766/most-liked-instagram-photos-in-a-city) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393108/how-can-i-find-the-most-liked-images-of-the-day-on-instagram) questions and answers. But these solutions returns just only ones that have been geotagged.

Maybe I can prepare a list of pages that have more than for example 500k followers and every day crawl their pages. But in this way I may lose some photos ...

Have you any idea what is the best to do?

PS: Recognizing Iranian people or Iranian pages is also a problem itself.

Comment: Hi @ashkan, where are your steps?

Comment: Hi @AndyK. As I said, I don't have any reasonable idea. These are spteps of the bad solution that is in my mind: 1- somehow find poeple and pages with many followers 2- Use Instagram's API to fetch their recent photos and check their like counts

Comment: http://mashable.com/2013/09/19/instagram-api-uses/